# Project structuring and file implementation in Python

Tags: python, project-structure

I am having a bit of troubles getting a grasp on how to structure my Python projects. I have read [jcalderone: Filesystem structure of a Python project](http://jcalderone.livejournal.com/39794.html) and been looking at the source code of [CouchApp](https://github.com/couchapp/couchapp), but I'm still feeling very puzzled.

I understand *how* the files should be structured, but I don't understand *why*. I would love if somebody could hook me up with a detailed walk-through of this, or could explain it to me. Simply how to set up a basic python project, and how the files would interact with each other.

I think this is definitely something people coming from other languages like C, C++, Erlang ... or people who have never been programming before, could benefit from.

Comment: Step 1.  Write a one-file application.  Step 2.  Understand the structure.  Seriously.  If you haven't attempted to write everything in a single file, it's very, very difficult to explain all the problems it creates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> name the directory something related to your project. When you do releases, you should include a version number suffix: Twisted-2.5.

Not sure why this is unclear.  It seems obvious. It all has to be in one directory.

Why do things have to be in one directory?  Because everyone says so, that's why.

> create a directory Twisted/bin and put your executables there.

This is the way Linux works.  Executables are in a `bin` directory.  It makes it easy to put this specific directory in your `PATH` environment variable.

> If your project is expressable as a single Python source file, then put it into the directory and name it something related to your project. For example, Twisted/twisted.py.

Right.  You have /Twisted, /Twisted/bin and /Twisted/twisted.py with your actual, running code in it.  Where else would you put it?

There's no "why" to this.  Where else could you possibly put it?

> If you need multiple source files, create a package instead (Twisted/twisted/, with an empty Twisted/twisted/**init**.py) and place your source files in it. For example, Twisted/twisted/internet.py.

This is just the way Python packages work.  They're directories with `__init__.py` files.  The tutorial is pretty clear on this.

> put your unit tests in a sub-package of your package Twisted/twisted/test/.

Where else would you put your tests?  Seriously.  There's no "why?" to this.  There's no sensible alternative.

> add Twisted/README and Twisted/setup.py to explain and install your software, respectively

Right.  Where else would you put them?   Again.  There's no "why?"  They go in the top directory because -- well -- that's what a directory is for.  It contains files.

Comment: What kinda throws me off by this, is that none of the python projects I have looked at, uses a structure like this. Something similar, but no `bin` or anything. It's this uncertainness that makes me doubt in what I should do.

Comment: @Chris Buchholz: "this uncertainness"?  What uncertainness?  Your question is utterly vague.  If you have specific doubts or topics or issues, please **update** the question to specifically address something specific.

Comment: I accept this answer because it provides the necessary information nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert in python but reading this lines from first link makes sense if you think that

- There might be computers/programs involved whit project
- There might be other people involved whit project

If you have consistent names and file structures both humans and computers might understand your complex program much better.

This involves topics like: testing, building, deploying, re-usability, searching, structure, consistency...

Standard makes connectivity.

Comment: I think I either did not explain it very well, or you misunderstood me. What I meant with _why_, is not why I should follow the structure that is regarded as "the structure", but _why_ the files and folders are placed like they are. E.g. Having a folder with the name of the program inside the top-level folder, and inside that folder having a <file>.py with the programs name. And how would that file be linked up with the rest of the program and so on. It's the _why_ as in needed details I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to answer to each rule:

1) You should have a root dir with a good name. If you make a tarball of your package, it's not considered good behavior to have files on the root. I feel *really* angry when I unpack something and the current folder ends up cluttered with junk.

2) You should separate your executables from modules. They are different beasts. And if you plan to use distutils, it will make your life easier.

3) If you have a single module, the reasons above don't appy. So you can simplify your tree.

4) Unit tests should be closely tighted to it's package. But they are not the package, so it's the perfect case for a subpackage.